# The e-mail message could not be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, email

I have a 2 server SharePoint farm.
All outgoing emails were working fine.

I just restarted both servers and now after that none of the emails are being sent. I am using OOB publishing workflow and it shows message:

```
The e-mail message could not be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly
```

Even if I setup Alert on some list, it doesn't send email.

I have checked that outgoing email setting in CA is defined and like I said it was working fine without problems but after restart it is showing error.

What could be the cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: Ok I changed the outgoing email address to something else and now it is sending email when I setup alerts on some list. But still workflow emails are not being sent. Let me remove and then add outgoing mail server again and then I will see if it works.

Comment: I removed outgoing mail server, added again and restart IIS but still emails from OOB workflow is not being sent. But email from Alerts are being sent. Don't know what to do now.

Comment: Try to restart SharePoint Timer service

Comment: I have already done that. Also restarted IIS and server itself but no luck.

Comment: I created a test workflow which sends email to user and it is also not sending email. But I am getting email from SharePoint regarding "variation" page changes as well as alerts which I told above.

Comment: I am facing same issue as you .Alerts are coming through from the document library but when workflows are fired I am getting the : System Account The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly. Wonder you got the same error with 'System Account' ?
What was anything different in the new SMTP server ? Thanks in advance Sujoy

Comment: @Sujoy I didn't do anything. Just getting new SMTP solved the problem. There was probably something at STMP end which infrastructure guys but I have no idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

It had something to do with SMTP. I got new SMTP from support and now emails are going fine.

But strange that SharePoint was able to send alert emails but not workflow.

Answer (score 2):

this might be a closed thread, but wanted to share the reason of the same error in my environment.

We also had same issue - multiple servers ***(couple of them newly joined to the farm).*** Only workflows used to fail with the error "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly".

The reason was that the 2 new servers were not added to the ***"SMTP server's relay servers list"*** (I am not an Exchange expert, but your Enterprise Exchange team will understand this).

Once we added the 2 new servers to the relay servers list, error is gone and everything started to work just fine.!